# Getting started with Node.js and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just started learning programming a couple weeks ago (currently working through JavaScript) and have no coding experience.  I’m doing fine so far with the language itself but I’m confused about how to implement what I am learning.  These are the steps I have taken so far and where I am confused.  Can anyone help guide me?

- I’m on a Windows PC
- Downloaded WebStorm for an IDE
- Downloaded and installed Console2 to act as a terminal
- Followed the instructions here (http://www.jhh.me/blog/2012/12/24/setting-up-http-server-on-windows-with-node-js/) to download and install Node.js.  As it reads, I installed the http server and started the server, using the file path for the JS and HTML files I have created in WebStorm
- Opened localhost and I see the directory of all the files I have created in WebStorm

My questions are:

- is Console2 even necessary?  Or am I covered by WebStorm?
- Do I ever need to type in Node itself?  It looks like a command prompt but I haven’t been able to execute anything through it
- If I stop the server by typing Ctrl-C in Console2 and selecting Y for Terminate Batch Job, why am I able to still see the directory of my files when I go to localhost?  Aren’t I accessing the server that I created here?  Or am I misunderstanding its use?
- Finally, I also followed the directions on sitepoint, copying the language into a JS file in WebStorm to also create a server.  The code executes in WebStorm and I see “Server is listening”.  However, I don’t understand the instructions “To start the server, type the command below…node web_server.js”.  Type this where?  In Console2?  In Node?  Is all this unnecessary since I have already created and run a server in the steps above?

Please forgive the basic nature of these questions.  I have found some great teaching sources online, but they often seem to conflict or omit steps, which is tough for a true beginner.

Thank you!

Brendan

Comment: Why the down vote? The old habit of drive off new users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Console2 is not necessary, [it is just a wrapper to a shell](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx) like `cmd.exe`
- I'm guessing you've gone into the [REPL function](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html).  Further explanation of [REPL at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).
- If the server has been terminated you won't be able to see any new stuff at `http://localhost`, what you'll see is cached content.
- They are explaining how to run it from a command prompt(`cmd.exe`).

Comment: Thank you!  Very helpful. To clarify on #2, I opened the Node.exe file and saw what looks like a prompt. Is this the REPLY function you're referring to?

Comment: @BrendanCahill Yes I was referring to the prompt.  Try pasting a `node.js` program there.